# Unable to assign value to key in Object in angular/typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I work on angular and I am unable to assign value to the key. My model is like below

```
export class aa{
    types: bb[];
}

export interface bb{
    name: string;
    age: string;
}
```

On my ts file, I did:

```
    newType: bb;

    initValues(){
    this.newType.name = 'Anna'; //error at this line
}
```

but I am getting an error as `cannot get property of undefined`.

Where am I going wrong? How can I assign value to a key in angular

Comment: newType: any; will do! Interfaces are of no use in javascript at the end! They are just for code writing convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have only declared the type of your `newType` property. You need also to initialize your property

```
newType: bb = { name: null, age: null };
```

Or you can say that the properties are optional and don't explicitly assign them `null`

```
export interface bb{
    name?: string;
    age?: string;
}

newType: bb = { };
```